# How can i set something on fixed position only when the content height fits in the screen height?

Tags: html, css

Let me explain.

I have a footer, that I want to be at the bottom of the screen. But, when the content of the page is shorter than the window (when there's no scrollbar), the footer is too high in the page, it is not at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `<footer>` with `id="footer"` and then this in CSS:

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%; }
```